# How to Change Telerik OpenAccess Namespace?

Tags: c#, telerik-open-access

I want to change the namespace of the complex types generated when creating a domain method.

When I right click on the type and go to `Properties`, there is a property called `Namespace`, but if I change it, it will only produce compile errors.

I tried changing the namespace in the code and that worked, but when updating the model, the namespace goes back to the default value.

Comment: What is the name of the namespace that you're attempting to use? Perhaps there's an illegal character or something similar...?

Comment: namespace i want: ComplexTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that changing the namespace of an individual object through the `Properties` tab will change the namespace for that code, but whenever OpenAccess regenerates the code, it will overwrite that change and use the namespace that is defined for the model.

You can change the namespace of the your model by right-clicking on the designer surface and selecting `Show Model Settings`.

This will open a window where you can specify a custom namespace; the screen looks like this:

[image: Model Settings Screen]

***Note:*** Keep in mind that this will change the namespace for all the domain classes & domain methods that are in the model.